# Azure DevOps build executing powershell script with args needs to be run twice in order to modify all necessary files by the ps script

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine, azure-pipelines

I'm having a hard time figuring out the root cause why the build pipeline needs to be run at least two times getting the output I'm expecting.

We've a powershell script that I've developed which basically retrieves translations and checks the xml files if an update is needed. Now if I run this script locally on my machine or locally on the VM where the build agent is hosted it's running fine and it updates all translations but not when run via the build pipeline

For example having 50 translations to update:

- run locally will update all 50 translations
- run locally on the vm will update all 50 translations
- running the script via azure build pipeline only 25 translations will be updated (and need a re-run)

I'm stuck as I can't debug the powershell script when executed by the build pipeline.

Has anyone an idea why the output of the powershell differs if run via an azure build pipeline vs. running it locally and locally on the vm? Any inputs are appreciated and don't hesitate to ask for further information if I'm missing something.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately without details about how the script is executed from the pipeline, the script itself, the output from a successful and unsuccessful run, and probably some sample of the target files being updated there isn't much guidance that can be provided.

Comment: Agree with scott, the issue is not detailed recorded. You could set variable system.debug to true in pipeline variable and queue a new build to get debug logs for further analysis. BTW, one free parallel job that can run for up to 60 minutes each time. Please make sure that your PowerShell job can be done within 60 minutes each time.

Comment: Hi Heimi, How about this issue? Do you manage to resolve it? If yes, could you please share your solution here, which will help others in the future?

Comment: I'll get back to you all as soon I'm working on it again. Thanks for the debug hints. I'll give it a try and come back with more information and details.